# will_paginate gem problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to use will_paginate-rails3 and its not working out here's what I have in my controller:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2 )

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
  end
end
```

Gemfile: `gem "will_paginate-rails3", '~> 3.0.pre'`

posts/index.html.erb: `<%= will_paginate @posts %>`

```
NoMethodError: NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x12c3438>):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Rendered C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.6ms)
```

Bundle install says the gem is there:

Anybody know where I made my mistake? Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use just

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

in my Gemfile and it works

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2 )

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
  end
end
```

Comment: added .all and still got error. Did a bundle install just to make sure and restarted development, still no luck

Comment: Hmm, I seem have run into this in the past. Let me see if I can dig up my old code.

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue... https://github.com/radiant/radiant/issues/221

Comment: tryed and didnt fix after adding require 'will_paginate'

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your Gemfile instead:

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
```

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but try adding `require 'will_paginate'` to the bottom of your environment.rb file

Comment: yeah read another post about adding require 'will_paginate' to the config/env/dev.rb file. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to delete the "all". I had the same problem, since I deleted the "all", it works now.
My code used to look like this :
.all.paginate :per_page => events_per_page, :page => params[:page]
delete the "all" before paginate. Hope it works for you. :)